# i am getting an error while upgrading apt upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, kali

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libwacom9 : Depends: libwacom-common (= 2.1.0-2) but 1.12-1 is to be installed
E: Broken packages          getting this error when using apt upgrade

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Kali forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Kali so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux* found in the on-topic link)  https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/

Comment: No package(s) in your paste match on-topic OS/releases. Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: I have met this in the soon-to-be-released Kubuntu 22.04 and solved it by installing `libwacom-common` and then (to avoid conflicts and other errors reported by `apt` in terminal *after* that) by simply using Discover instead of other tools.

Answer (score 29):

same issue today.
if you need to or want to keep the package like me, just run:

```
sudo apt install libwacom-common
```

it will install the missing package and after that

```
sudo apt update
```

It will run like a train.

Comment: Thanks. Running like a Japanese bullet train

Comment: After that, in 22.04 updates couldn't be made with apt in terminal, because of all upgradable packages being held back, but Discover worked just fine.

Answer (score 6):

You need to remove the package:

1. sudo apt remove libwacom2
2. sudo apt upgrade

I hope it works for you.

Comment: Why would you remove the package? Please give supporting info for your answer.

Comment: Because it was a problem with dependencies. If you want to install the new version of libwacom, go to this page https://github.com/linuxwacom/libwacom/releases/tag/libwacom-2.1.0

Comment: Thx, fixed the same issue on Debian Bookworm

Comment: libwacom2 seems absent in Ubuntu.